# encoding errors when replacing unwanted characters in utf-8 encoded file

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

Code can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/kelrien/pyretrieval/

whenever I execute my `example.py`, the following error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "example.py", line 21, in <module>
    docs.append(proc.process(line.decode("utf-8")))
  File "pyretrieval\processor.py", line 61, in process
    tokens = self.tokenize(string)
  File "pyretrieval\processor.py", line 47, in tokenize
    temp = temp.replace(char, self.replace_characters[char])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As you can see - the error happens when trying to replace german umlauts I specified. If I don't use the replace_characters dict and just ignore those umlauts, I'm not getting the error.

I already tried a lot of stuff:

- Using the codecs module
- Using encode("utf-8") and decode("utf-8") at different

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had to encode the characters I wanted to replace in unicode too(in processor.py).

I already pushed the necessary changes to github. https://github.com/kelrien/pyretrieval